# Retrieve one id referred by two ids

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck with the following problem:

SQL query for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `thread_users` (
  `thread_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`thread_id`,`user_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Let's say that I have those data:

```
INSERT INTO `thread_users` (`thread_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 1),
(3, 4);
```

I need to retrieve the thread_id referred by only 2 ids: X & Y (both known).
With the above data, I want to be able to retrieve the thread_id where only user_id = 1 & user_id = 2 are present.

What i Know for sure about this table:

- If a thread is composed by only 2 users, there is no other threads containing only those two ids. (It's check outside mysql before the insertion)
- A user can't be present in a thread more than once. (primary key)

What i have thinking of to resolve this problem:

- Sum up (user_id 1 + user_id 2) search for SUMs equal to that result + (user_id = X OR user_id = Y). But i haven't been able to write correctly this query AND I also need to check the number of user_id in that thread...
- Obviously: searching id where the number of user_id on threads are equal to 2 and where user_id are equals to X & Y.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Not quite sure about what you are asking :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tu1.thread_id
FROM thread_users AS tu1
INNER JOIN thread_users AS tu2
  ON tu1.thread_id = tu2.thread_id
  AND tu1.user_id <> tu2.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN thread_users AS tu3
  ON tu1.thread_id = tu3.thread_id
  AND tu1.user_id <> tu3.user_id
  AND tu2.user_id <> tu3.user_id
WHERE tu1.user_id = 1
  AND tu2.user_id = 2
  AND tu3.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Check again with the edited answer. There used to be a type in my last line.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
SELECT thread_id FROM thread_users WHERE user_id IN(1,2) GROUP BY thread_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id)=2
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0388c/1)

Comment: Hi, the problem is that the thread_id 2 is fetch. I want the thread containing only those 2 ids.

Comment: I don't follow you,it gets the thread_id having user_id 1 and 2.Both 1 and 2 have user_id(1,2).Could you clarify?

Comment: user 1 & 2 are present both on thread 1 & 2. But in the thread 2 there is also user 3. I want to only retrieve the thread id where the user X & Y are present, and only them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit simpler than the JOIN example, and also a bit faster:

```
SELECT `thread_id`, GROUP_CONCAT(`user_id`) AS this_match FROM `thread_users` 
GROUP BY `thread_id` HAVING this_match = '1,2'
```

Comment: I made changes above that I think make this a better solution.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But i prefer the answer given by olwald in term of optimization. Again, thanks to have tried to help me :) (i have explain both queries, and your is hitting more rows)

Comment: You right for this example, but if you change the data, then joining to itself in some cases can lead to a cartesian product, which could be higher than mine.  Plus the other solution will not work for user_ids over 3.  When you have four, you'll have to add another join.

Comment: Yeah, I guess if I want to be able to found a thread with only 3 distinct user in it I will have to add a condition (and so on for more). But I do not need it (and probably never since i have other ways to access data when ids > 2)